# Silverlight 4 RichTextBox scroll to bottom

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am writing a chat application with Silverlight. I am adding the content dynamically to the rich text box and I need to scroll it down to show the last messages. But there is no way to do that. All documentation/codes that I have found on internet are old.

Any solution will be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled with this for a long time in my own application. The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke method wasn't reliable for me; sometimes it would scroll to the bottom, other times it wouldn't. The only way to make it work was to nest two Dispatcher.BeginInvoke calls inside each other, but I didn't like that solution.

Instead of using Dispatcher, I abuse event handlers. In this example, the text box will scroll to the bottom only if it was there at the time the new Inline was added (a useful behavior for chat boxes, to allow users to read previous messages if they want). You can pass a Run object as the Inline parameter.

```
private void AddInline(Inline inline)
{
    var viewer = textBox.GetChildByType<ScrollViewer>(item => item.Name == "ContentElement") as ScrollViewer;
    bool scrollToBottom = viewer.VerticalOffset == viewer.ScrollableHeight;

    // Creating the paragraph isn't necessary.
    // In my own application, I only add a single paragraph to the RichTextBox that displays my chat messages.
    // Then I just add new Inlines to the single paragraph.
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.Inlines.Add(inline);

    if (scrollToBottom)
        textBox.LayoutUpdated += ScrollRichTextBoxToBottom;

    // Adding the paragraph triggers a layout update.
    // In the LayoutUpdated handler, the viewer will be scrolled to the bottom, triggering a second layout pass.
    textBox.Blocks.Add(p);
}

private void ScrollRichTextBoxToBottom(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The LayoutUpdated handler needs to be removed, otherwise the RichTextBox becomes unscrollable.
    textBox.LayoutUpdated -= ScrollRichTextBoxToBottom;

    var viewer = textBox.GetChildByType<ScrollViewer>(item => item.Name == "ContentElement") as ScrollViewer;
    viewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(viewer.ScrollableHeight);
}
```

Note: GetChildByType is just an extension method to get the ScrollViewer. (I did not create this extension method.)

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetChildByType<T>(this UIElement element, Func<T, bool> condition)
        where T : UIElement
    {
        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        GetChildrenByType<T>(element, condition, results);
        if (results.Count > 0)
            return results[0];
        else
            return null;
    }

    private static void GetChildrenByType<T>(UIElement element, Func<T, bool> condition, List<T> results)
        where T : UIElement
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            UIElement child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as UIElement;
            if (child != null)
            {
                T t = child as T;
                if (t != null)
                {
                    if (condition == null)
                        results.Add(t);
                    else if (condition(t))
                        results.Add(t);
                }
                GetChildrenByType<T>(child, condition, results);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to dig out the ScrollViewer that is part of the RichTextBox template.  You can do this with the help of some code based of `VisualTreeHelper`.  Get the code for my `VisualTreeEnumeration` class [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx).

Now with this class in your project you can do this:-

```
ScrollViewer sv = rtb.Descendents().OfType<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();
```

**Full Example**

Create a new application and include the `VisualTreeEnumeration` class.

In MainPage.xaml use the following xaml:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb" />
    <Button Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

In its code behind add this:-

```
    int i = 0;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "Hello " + (i++).ToString() });
        rtb.Blocks.Add(p);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            ScrollViewer sv = rtb.Descendents().OfType<ScrollViewer>().FirstOrDefault();
            sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sv.ScrollableHeight);
            sv.UpdateLayout();
        });
    }
```

Note the use of BeginInvoke to allow the RTB to sort itself out after having added the text.  Using BeginInvoke queues up the rest of the code on the UI thread dispatcher.

Comment: Don't want to put you down or anything but you reinvented the wheel with your `VisualTreeEnumeration`. The exact same functionality is available via the Silverlight Toolkit. The namespace `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives` will give you extension methods like `myElement.GetVisualDescendants()`.

Comment: @herzmeister:  Whilst its true that there are many Xaps that use the toolkit not everyone needs it.  I have a number projects that use my enumeration stuff that have no need for the toolkit and at 351KB including the toolkit just for this feature would not seem to be a good trade off.  I'm also especially loathe to recommend adding the toolkit overhead in questions where the presence of the toolkit is not even mentioned.  Even then I avoid it in case another reader might choose to include it just to get a feature that as my blog demonstrates can be done in very little code.

Comment: Well it is kinda working but the problem is that the scrollbar is scrolling down then immediately gets back to the previous position. I cannot figure out the reason of that.

Comment: @Heka: Are you running this code immediately after adding new text?  You might try wrapping it in a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in an attempt to let the RichTextBox to sort itself out before you re-position the scroll bar

Comment: @Heka: BTW how are you adding a new message?  Using the `rtb.Blocks.Add` method?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones I am using something like this:    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
{
          Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
          paragraph.Inlines.Add(message);
          rtbMessages.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
});    And I am scrolling immediately after calling begin invoke.

Comment: @Heka:  You need to use BeginInvoke __after__ callinf Add.  You are probably using BeginInvoke initially to move to the UI Thread from a background thread where the message is received.  So in your case you need to do it twice.  Once to shift threads and another to queue up work after the RTB has had a chance to do other things.

Comment: I tried exactly the same and still doesn't work. But thanks @AnthonyWJones this example is quite informative.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need neither extensions methods nor dispatchers. The easiest way to scroll the RichTexBox control to the bottom is as follows:

**textBox.Selection.Select(textBox.ContentEnd, textBox.ContentEnd);**

You can achieve the "scroll to top" behaviour in the similar fashion.

Hope that helps.